# How to order values by occurrence of certain values?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following table:

```
| Jon | "a" |
| Eva | "b" |
| Jon | "a" |
| Eva | "a" |
| Eva | "b" |
```

I would like to get unique values from the first column (names) ordered by number of rows where (for the considered name) the second column has value "a" divided by the number of columns containing the considered name.

For example for Eva the number of rows with "a" is 1, and total number of columns with Eva is 3. So, the parameter for the ordering will be equal 0.33(3).

Can anybody, pleas, help me with that.

Comment: And then what about "b"?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  name
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        name
ORDER BY
        SUM(letter = 'a') / COUNT(*)
```